# Dialogflow default date parameter

Tags: dialogflow-es

I can't find any in the documentation, is there a way to set a parameter default value to a dynamic value like for example "today" ?

if as a default value I put "today" or "@sys.date" it is used as string, and not as the date value

Comment: Have you tried using Date objects in your webhook fulfillment? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: i don't understand the suggestion, i have a python backend that receives dialogflow data, my necessity is to avoid having the "default case" logic in the application, when a date parameter is in the intent. Dialogflow allows to setup a default parameter, i can't find if it is possible to have "today" as a default value, that is then exposed to the server in a formatted syntax, not the string "today"

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't set dynamic default values for parameters in Dialogflow. You'd need to implement this on the back-end, as you suspected.

The only dynamic elements that can be used for default parameter values [are extracted either from the original user utterance, the context, or a composite entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/actions-parameters).